# Use of a preposition with a gerund

Tags: prepositions

> Appearing of white hair in beard is a sign of old age.

Is this a right sentence? Do we need the preposition 'of' in this? If this is wrong, then what about the following?

> Appearance of white hair in beard is a sign of old age.

Although I believe this one is  much better:

> A white hair appearing in beard is a sign of old age.

Yet, my question is if the first sentence is grammatically correct?

Answer (score 2):

In your sentence, **white hair** is the subject of the gerund **appearing**. It does not require a preposition, but it must be placed before the verb:

> white hair appearing in [the/a/one's] beard is a sign of old age.

Similarly, an object must follow the gerund:

> Wasting time should be avoided

Anything other than subject and object can be attached with a preposition:

> Living in France is a big advantage if you want to learn French.

---

Note that you **beard** is a countable noun, so when you use it in the singular it needs an article (a/the) or, for example, a possessive pronoun (one's).